# Why is this PLC TON not getting activated in Studio 5000 v32.11

Tags: timer, plc

The timer on Rung 0 should be timing but it is not.

The PLC is online and in live mode and the logic before the timer is true.
This is running on a CompactLogix L16ER.

[image: PLC Main Routine Online.]

[image: Timer tag]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your first picture, the left-most rail of the ladder is not green. It looks like that entire routine is not running.

Comment: You are correct, I am not sure why, next time I am in the lab I will look at it more. It is a single routine. Most likely a problem in the tags? Is there a list of things that will make the rails not light up?

Comment: Most likely just an issue with how the routine is set up. Check that it's in a running task (usually just in the continuous task) and make sure it is the main routine of its program (Program Properties -> Configuration tab).

Answer (score 0):

In your program properties for the program/task your using, go to "Program Properties" then to the "Configuration"  Set your main program to the desired program you're trying to use.

[image]